# C# Set Specific Start & End Position For Each Item Of A String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, listbox

I'm attempting to read the names of all files in a specific folder, then add each file name as an item in a listbox. The issue, is when doing so my listbox is displaying the full file path.

I've tried several various things and feel as if this should be incredibly easy to remove "C:\Client\TestFolder\" & ".txt" from each item. However nothing seems to be working :( any assistance is very much appreciated!

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Client\TestFolder\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(filePaths);
        string[] titleArray = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            titleArray[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
        }

        Array.Sort(titleArray);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < titleArray.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(titleArray[i].ToString());
        }
```

For example if the file path C:\Client\TestFolder\ contained 3 .txt files:

1. test1.txt
2. test2.txt
3. test3.txt

My listbox will display:

1. C:\Client\TestFolder\test1.txt
2. C:\Client\TestFolder\test2.txt
3. C:\Client\TestFolder\test3.txt

Desired results:

1. test1
2. test2
3. test3

Comment: Look up the documentation for the `System.IO.Path` class. It provides methods you might need/want to solve your problem... ;-)

Comment: [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: If you want [C# file name from path](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+file+name+from+path) it is covered in duplicate, if you are looking for something else - please [edit] post to clarify... as code/title of what you are trying to do is complicated but sample of what you want to achieve for some reason look simply file names.

Comment: Tangential side note: You don't need to make the detour of of first adding the path strings to the listbox to just take them out again and replace them anyway. Its just useless work your program is doing there. Just manipulate and sort the `filePaths` array you got from `Directory.GetFiles` directly, and then fill the listbox once from this array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8).

Example using your code:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Client\TestFolder\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(filePaths);
string[] titleArray = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    titleArray[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
}

Array.Sort(titleArray);
listBox1.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < titleArray.Length; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(titleArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: Incoming nitpick ;-) Why is there a `.ToString()` in  `titleArray[i].ToString()`?

Comment: Yes, you can also drop off your .ToString()...not needed; I simply added the 'GetFileNameWithoutExtension' to their original code.

Comment: @elgonzo Cannot Implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'

Comment: @PatrickBruinsma, there are no values or references of type `object` involved there. You seem to confuse something or look at an error that is related to a completely different code line elsewhere (note that my comment was specifically about `titleArray[i].ToString()`)